# JHipster prod content missing

Tags: material-design, angular-material, jhipster

I'm using Gradle (**./gradlew -Pprod bootRepackage**) to deploy my JHipster app to a production server (Wildfly 10).  It's mostly working, but there is some content missing.  Here are two examples (prod on the left, local dev environment on the right):

[image]

[image]

I don't see any errors logged, either in the Chrome console or Wildfly server log.

Here is the block that isn't showing on the first page:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <a href="http://ca.linkedin.com/in/yvoncomeau"><span class="linked-in-button img-responsive img-rounded"></span></a>
        <br/><br/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <a href="https://roundwheeltech.wordpress.com/"><span class="wordpress-button img-responsive img-rounded"></span></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

... the CSS for those image classes, plus two other images that DO work (roundwheel-logo and roundwheel-cirle):

```
.roundwheel-logo {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 300px;
    height: 91px;
    background: url("../images/roundwheeltechnologies-2x.jpg") no-repeat center top;
    background-size: contain;
}

.linked-in-button {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 160px;
    height: 33px;
    background: url("../images/linkedinprofilebutton.gif") no-repeat center top;
    background-size: contain;
}

.wordpress-button {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 160px;
    height: 33px;
    background: url("../images/wordpress-logo-hoz-bg.png") no-repeat center top;
    background-size: contain;
}

.roundwheel-cirle {
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 113px;
    background: url("../images/rw-circle.png") no-repeat center top;
    background-size: contain;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

...

and where those images were placed:

[image]

The war file does contain the images, timestamped:

[image]

... and the minified CSS references the correct timestamped versions.

Comment: You should first find out whether it's a packaging issue or a server issue. So is it working when using executable jar with prod profile?

Comment: It's the same behaviour when I run it using the prod executable jar.

Comment: So I can,'t believe ter's no error in Chrome console, you should see some 404 errors.

Comment: As only some images and CSS are missing, I suppose that you didn't put them in expected locations and so when jhipster build process minifies and versions them, HTML code does not get rewritten and still points to the original path not including the version timestamp.

Comment: The first of the pages above gives this error:  http://..[ip]../api/account?cacheBuster=1476448351226 401 (Unauthorized), which seems normal (I'm not logged in).  The second page has no errors.

Comment: I've added more details about the code that isn't showing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why this worked, but I modified the source by moving an inner row out and into a new row (new version on the right):

[image]

This solves the home page issue:

[image]

The contact form issue was fixed with a more minor HTML change.  This:

```
<h4 data-translate="contact.intro"/>
```

... was changed to this:

```
<h4 data-translate="contact.intro">Please fill out the form...</h4>
```

... and all of the markup below that tag (ie. the form) appeared.

Comment: For your form, it's probably a JS issue, I saw you're using angular-material-design and putting $.material.init() directly in your page, I guess it should be in your angular module config block. Anyway this is not a JHipster issue.

Comment: The $.material.init() in index.html was an attempted fix (based on Matt Raible's minibook) that had no impact.

Comment: Anyway as this is very likely an issue in your angular code, you could try to put a breakpoint and compare between dev and prod.